# Correlations between 2 columns for all columns

Tags: python, correlation

I have 2 arrays each of which has n columns so that two arrays are identical in shape structure.
The issue i came across was that i couldn't calculate correlations between two columns for all columns. I need a correlation for `W1[:, 0] and W2[:, 0]` and another one for  instance `W1[:, 1] and W2[:, 1]` and so on and so forth till the last column. How can one accomplish that ?

```
steps_per_year = 12
n_years = 1
n_scenarios = 5
n_steps = steps_per_year * n_years

W1 = np.random.normal(size = (n_steps, n_scenarios))
W2 = np.random.normal(size = (n_steps, n_scenarios))
```

Answer (score 1):

Correlations are just normalized scalar products, so you can do something like this:

```
W1_copy = np.copy(W1)
W2_copy = np.copy(W2)
W1_copy -= np.mean(W1_copy, axis=0)
W1_copy /= np.linalg.norm(W1_copy, axis=0)
W2_copy -= np.mean(W2_copy, axis=0)
W2_copy /= np.linalg.norm(W2_copy, axis=0)
correlations = np.dot(np.transpose(W1_copy), W2_copy)
```

If I'm not mistaken, `correlations[i, j]` will hold the correlation of the ith column of `W1` and jth column of `W2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
But something wrong if u calculate the correlation of 2 first columns u will get different result

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem. Correlation of the first columns of both matrices would be `correlations[0, 0]`